# Macros in for loop in Stata

Tags: loops, local, stata

I have local variables `x1 , x2, and x3` as follows

```
local x1 2 3 5
local x2 5 9 7
local x3 1 3 4
```

Now I define `local x` as

```
local x `x1' `x2' `x3'
```

Next, I define for loop as

```
 foreach var of varlist `x'{
    reg y `var'}
```

The problem is that stata is giving me the error (note `y` is dependent variable)

```
invalid name
```

Any suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are locals `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` macros of variable names? What are 1-9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think of macros as "delayed typing". This is the approach I use.

```
sysuse auto, clear
local x1 weight
local x2 headroom trunk
local x3 length turn

forvalue i = 1/3 {
    regress price `x`i''
}
```

Comment: I also tried that one but I had a `x' instead of 'x`. Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these are variables, Richardh's solution would obviously work.  However it requires that you rename all your macros even though that's not necessary.

You can just expanding the macros twice:

```
local x x1 x2 x3
foreach var of local x {
   reg y ``var''
}
```

You could also do this, but you'll have problems if your lists of variables are too long:

```
local x "`x1'" "`x2'" "`x3'" 
foreach var of local x {
  reg y `var'
}
```